# Why are these constraints in UITableViewCell ambiguous?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell, it looks like this:

[image]

The warning I'm getting is:

> Inequality Constraint Ambiguity: trailing >= date.trailing + 16

I highlighted the constraint in the picture above.

What I don't understand is, before 'someView' (the last view in the bottom) was added, there was no warning; When it was added **without height = 20** constraint, there was no warning. However, as soon as the height constraint was added, I start to get the warning message.

I have to add the height constraint because without the it, the height of 'someView' is not 20 anymore.

If it helps, I am using

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

to decide the height of a row

Comment: This is not an answer really, but I would suggest not worrying too much about what Xcode says in Interface Builder about whether there is ambiguity here. It doesn't always get this right. Instead, the run the app and see what happens. In particular, run the app and switch to the View Debugger and see what _it_ says. If there is ambiguity, it will tell you loud and clear (exclamation marks). If not, no problem.

Comment: @matt Thanks. You're right, cells are displayed correctly. However, the debugger does complain: `Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. ..........   Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d7f660 UILabel:0x7fba44c3ca60'Name Label'.height == 24   (active)>`. So basically, it's removing the height constraint of nameLabel. Do you think I should just ignore the warning (both in console and IB) because cells are displayed correctly?

Comment: Whoa, that's not ambiguity. It's the opposite of ambiguity. It's _conflict_. Conflict is real and you need to do something about it. - You should still do what I said, by the way. Use the View Debugger on the app while it's running. It will tell you very clearly whether you have ambiguity or conflict and it's the only really good way to know both.

Comment: Set a `width` constraint on your button.

Comment: I don't see any relation with the some view height and the warning with the trailing constraint. one is vertical and one is horizontal. this shouldn't be the case. they don't conflict each other.

Comment: can you share your storyboard with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the same UI of yours in `UITableViewCell`:

[image]

The fields with width , height and aspect ratio has constraints as :

[image]

and all the remaining `constraints are as follows:

[image]

The only difference is I guess the height constraint to `Name Label`. If I am adding that then I am getting constraint conflict issues. Removing that is not showing any issues and UI is also perfectly fine.

Hope this helps to figure out and fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

You’ve added a lot of unneeded heights for a dynamic cell.  I honestly hate seeing labels with height constraints, as contentSize will set that height for you. When I used to run into layout issues, my Senior IOS Developer would tell me to delete it all and start again, lol.  I would suggest this but it would be a terrible answer.  It’s also bad practice to have placeholder text in your labels/views.  For some reason interface builder hates it.  Just some tips.

You can download the example here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02066350701605990856

Comment: Also have you tried removing the aspect ratio from the textView?  You have a top, leading, trailing and bottom already defined.

Comment: So you answer is "delete everything and start all over"? Setting a height constraint can improve performance though

Comment: I don't think that having place holders should be an issue at all. I leave the default text. but, instead he can name them on the left pane of the storyboard. it makes life easier.

Comment: you are right about the height constraints on the labels. one should avoid it.